# How to identify wheather without clicking the local notification has come or not?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, localnotification

I need to reschedule the notification even if the user doesnt click the notification. I know that the did receive local notification gets called when the user taps the notification. Is there any way by which I can identify that the notification has arrived and user have not done anything with the notification. Any delegate method which gives this information.

Comment: You have to build it yourself in the didReceiveLocalNotification

Comment: didReceiveLocalNotification doesn't get called until you tap on the notification or open the application.  I need to set up action when sound of local notification comes not when use taps the notification.

Comment: The thing you need is not possible, I've tried before to store the notification in a local data base, but I reached a dead end

Comment: Apple must think of this .This seems essential

Comment: its really essential. apple should give a thought on this